# Is there a way to retrieve upload parts to s3

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, client

I am doing a multipart upload to S3 from the client. Let's say an upload failed to complete, maybe because of the parts not being in order or maybe because completeMultiPartUpload never being called.

Is there a way to retrieve the parts that have been uploaded to S3 but are not finalised? So I can try to fix the MultiPart upload?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it help? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListMultipartUploads.html

Comment: In looking at that documentation, it does _not_ seem possible to retrieve a part. It can only be used to _complete_ an upload, or the parts can be deleted when the upload is aborted.

Comment: Really a bummer that they don't provide the option to retrieve the actual data. If anyone has any news on this, happy to hear!